# Make a hyperlink to a ClearCase file?

Tags: clearcase

In ClearCase, is there anyway to make a straight hyperlink to file?  Like of the form

```
http://mysite/myfile
```

where all a user has to do is click on the link to view a page or download a file?

We have several non-technical people at our organization who want to look at some of the documentation that developers are storing on ClearCase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, you can try and version (add to source control) an [xxx.lnk file: a shortcut file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.lnk), which is set to open an http url.

Once loaded in a snapshot view (or even accessed in a dynamic view), a simple click should open a browser.

An even simpler solution would be to store an `xxx.html` static page, which would:

- open the same browser when double-clicked
- list all the actual documentation urls you want.

One file, multiple links!